# Erros lançados no Android não são facilmente capturados no XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo em XamarinForms  um projeto onde utilizo várias APIS baixadas pelo NuGet, e não tive problemas até agora.

Até que então resolvi utilizar o plugin **ImageCircle** e criar uma nova View no meu projeto.

O aplicativo android aborta, o Visual Studio para o debug, e tenho simplismente esta mensagem no debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo este e outros erros desta forma? Como tenho mais informações?
Preciso ter segurança que não vou perder tanto tempo pra descobrir um erro que não tenho a informação dele.

Já realizei build, clean e rebuild.
Já tentei utilizar o logcat interno. Ele fecha assim que a apk aborta.
Já reiniciei a máquina e atualizei as referências.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Joaquim,

Tente atualizar Xamarin no seu Visual Studio, pois na versão 4.3.1 se não me engano eles corrigiram um erro relacionado a SIGSEGV.

Siga esse material que pode te ajudar a implementar.
https://blog.xamarin.com/elegant-circle-images-in-xamarin-forms/

Espero ter ajudado.